# TypeError: users.map is not a function - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

> I'm trying to get all data into a table and I'm using reactjs and hooks to implement CRUD so I gott this error please can someone help me to fix this issue.

> Here is the code :

```
const [car, setCarh] = useState(initialState)
    
      useEffect(()=> {
          retrieveCars();
          
        }, [])
    
        const retrieveCars =() =>{
          DataService.getAll()
          .then(response => {
            
             setCarh(response.data) 
           
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
           
        }
    <tbody>
                    {
                      cars.map((data) => (
                        <tr >
                        
                        <th scope="row">{data.idCars}</th>  
                      
                      <td>{data.carName}</td>
                      <td>{data.carModel}</td>
                      <td>
                      <Link to={"/classement/update/" + data.idCars}
                        className="btn btn-info"
                        >
                        Edit
                       </Link>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the code is relevant to the error message as I see no declaration of `users` anywhere. If we are looking at the `map` applied to `cars` here, `map` is a function of arrays, so make sure `cars` is an array.

Comment: Please add a better code that relates to the question. and the map function is an array method, so make sure that `users` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong variable... You need to change `cars.map` to `car.map`